# First letter styled

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I want to have a styled text in JTextPane, here is a listener to JTextPane:

```
 private CaretListener listener = new CaretListener() {

    @Override
     public void caretUpdate(CaretEvent e) {
        StyleConstants.setBold(sas, false);
        helpTextPane.setCharacterAttributes(sas, true);
     }
};
```

the problem ist that the first letter is bold (i do not want it): [image]

I know that the problem is with the attributes and i need resetet these attributes but how ?

Comment: Sorry for a little unformatted source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use InputAttributes to set/reset the bold.

```
MutableAttributeSet sas=((StyledEditorKit)yourTextPane.getEditorKit()).getInputAttributes();
```

Comment: Where should I code your line ? (in listner I try but i am not sure where)

Comment: First place is the caret listener but could be some another places e.g. on button click.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was with the StyledEditorKit which was automatically overrided and I have had to code a CustomStyledEditorKit.

Comment: I would suggest another solution. Just wrap the input attributes change in SwingUtilities.invokeLater in the caret listener